# React Native app stuck on blank white screen with iOS simulator

Tags: react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I built my application with the Facebook login feature for iOS last week.

I don't know why but when I opened my app today I get this strange error.

** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/alan2305/dougo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jschelpers.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JSCWrapper.o /Users/alan2305/dougo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jschelpers/JSCWrapper.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        CompileC /Users/alan2305/dougo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jschelpers.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Value.o /Users/alan2305/dougo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jschelpers/Value.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        CompileC /Users/alan2305/dougo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jschelpers.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JSCHelpers.o /Users/alan2305/dougo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jschelpers/JSCHelpers.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        CompileC /Users/alan2305/dougo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jschelpers.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unicode.o /Users/alan2305/dougo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jschelpers/Unicode.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dougo.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
        Failed to chmod /Users/alan2305/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/27A18B40-AF2B-4FDF-A98C-796B1E53CC7B/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Bundle/Application/535974D3-D4A0-4EB1-AEE1-F7CBC7107F9B/dougo.app/dougo : No such file or directory
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.dougo
org.reactjs.native.example.dougo: 54919
```

Not able to find the solution to fix this please help.

[here is my terminal error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5cMH.jpg)

[here is my XCode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMHNg.jpg)